# Hive and SparkSQL do not support datetime type?

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql

Is it true that `Hive` and `SparkSQL` do not support the datatype of `datetime`?

From my reading of the references, they seem to support only `date` and `timestamp`.  The former does not a time component (i.e. hour, minute, and second); the latter has high precision (down to millisecond) but is not very human readable (it always require a conversion by `from_unixtime()` or `date_format()`, and the result would be a string, not a `datetime` type).

In contrast, other database systems, such as `MySQL` does have a datatype of `datetime`. (E.g. see this [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html))

Any good suggestions/tips how to work around this limitation?

These are my references:

1. [Hive Language Manual: Date/Time Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Date/TimeTypes)
2. [Hive Language Manual: Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

**Updated: On human readability**

Here I give an example on `MySQL` to illustrate my point
about human-readability:

```
-- MySQL code 
select 
  cast(now() as date)         as asDate,          -- human readable
  cast(now() as dateTime)     as asDateTime,      -- human readable  
  unix_timestamp(now())       as asUnixTimestamp, -- not H/R
  cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now())) 
        as dateTime) 
                              asDateTimeAgain     -- cast into dateTime to make it H/R
```

The display would be this:

(Pay attention to the fourth column `asDateTimeAgain`, which is human readable)

```
+------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| asDate     | asDateTime          | asUnixTimestamp | asDateTimeAgain     |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2017-10-21 | 2017-10-21 22:37:15 |      1508625435 | 2017-10-21 22:37:15 |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the limitation is not just about human-readability.  A string 
representation of `datetime` is
human readable, but then it lost the property of `datetime` and
*will require* further conversion back into `datatime` for date/time processing,
such as `min()`, `max()`, and capturing the values into `java.util.Date`

```
-- Hive/SparkSQL  code
select 
  current_date                    asDate,
  unix_timestamp()                asUnixTimestamp,
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')        asString
```

The output would be this, where the third column is a string and not
a `datetime` type

```
------------------------------------------------------
| asDate     | asUnixTimestamp | asString            |
| ---------- | --------------- | ------------------- |
| 2017-10-21 | 1508625586      | 2017-10-21 22:39:46 |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(I am providing the answer myself here)

**Do not confuse `timestamp` with"unix timestamp"**

`timestamp` is actually human readable; while "unix timestamp", being
the number of seconds/milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, is indeed
not very human readable.

However, we can use `cast()` to convert the latter (through a function `from_unixtime()`)
to get the former.

```
-- Hive/SparkSQL  code
select 
  current_date                    asDate,          -- human readable
  unix_timestamp()                asUnixTimestamp, -- not human readable
  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) asString,        -- human readable
  cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())             
    as date)                      asDate2,         -- human readable
  cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())             
    as timestamp)                 asTimestamp      -- human readable
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| asDate     | asUnixTimestamp | asString            | asDate2    | asTimestamp           |
| ---------- | --------------- | ------------------- | ---------- | --------------------- |
| 2017-10-22 | 1508687321      | 2017-10-22 15:48:41 | 2017-10-22 | 2017-10-22 15:48:41.0 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

`Timestamp` does what you want.  I'm not sure what you mean by "human-readable".  All databases store dates and date times in an internal format, that is not at all related to the display format.  And -- to a close approximation -- the internal formats are different for different databases.  (Wikipedia has a fun [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) on some of the different "0" dates used by different computer systems.)

If you want to see the value in a particular way, then format the result as a string.  Hive has a full complement of string functions for handling `timestamp` values, and it easily converts string literals into timestamps, when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I updated my question to clarify on what I mean by "human readability".  Please check and comment.

Comment: Actually my problem may be related to another issue.  If you can, please also take a look of my another question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869005/hive-sparksql-how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-into-a-timestamp-not-string  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @leeyuiwah . . . Hive does tend to be pretty flexible about conversions between strings and internal formats.

Comment: Thanks!  But I can't find a way to convert a unix timestamp to timestamp (the internal format), and this is a major road block that I am currently having.  I thought this should be easy but maybe I am missing something.  Can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869005/hive-sparksql-how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-into-a-timestamp-not-string