# Hive/SparkSQL: How to convert a Unix timestamp into a timestamp (not string)?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I thought this would be easy ...

In Hive/SparkSQL, how do I convert a unix timestamp [Note 1] into a `timestamp`
data type?

(Note 1: That is, number of seconds/milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970)

I thought `from_unixtime()` would do that, but it gives back a string
instead of a timestamp.  The following experiment illustrates the problem

**Step 0: Preparation**

```
select 
  from_unixtime(1508673584) as fut;
```

Result:

```
-----------------------
| fut                 |
| ------------------- |
| 2017-10-22 11:59:44 |
-----------------------
```

**Step 1: Create a table with the result of `from_unixtime()`**

```
create table test
select 
  from_unixtime(1508673584) as fut;
```

**Step 2: Examine the datatype of the column `fut`**

```
describe test;
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------
| col_name | data_type | comment |
| -------- | --------- | ------- |
| fut      | string    | <null>  |
----------------------------------
```

I also tried this

```
select 
  from_utc_timestamp(1508618794*1000, 'EDT');
```

According to the manual (link [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)), this should work.  Because it
states that:

> Coverts a timestamp* in UTC to a given timezone (as of Hive 0.8.0). *
>   timestamp is a primitive type, including timestamp/date,
>   tinyint/smallint/int/bigint, float/double and decimal. Fractional
>   values are considered as seconds. Integer values are considered as
>   milliseconds.. E.g from_utc_timestamp(2592000.0,'PST'),
>   from_utc_timestamp(2592000000,'PST') and from_utc_timestamp(timestamp
>   '1970-01-30 16:00:00','PST') all return the timestamp 1970-01-30
>   08:00:00

However, I got an error of

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
  cannot resolve 'from_utc_timestamp((1508618794 * 1000), 'EDT')' 
  due to data type mismatch: 
  argument 1 requires timestamp type, 
  however, '(1508618794 * 1000)' is of int type.; line 2 pos 2;
'Project [unresolvedalias(from_utc_timestamp((1508618794 * 1000), EDT), None)]
+- OneRowRelation$

SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am providing an answer myself here.)

The answer is to use `cast()`.  This works for both `date` and `timestamp`

```
select 
  from_unixtime(1508673584)                    as fut,
  cast(from_unixtime(1508673584) as date)      as futAsDate,
  cast(from_unixtime(1508673584) as timestamp) as futAsTimestamp;
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| fut                 | futAsDate  | futAsTimestamp        |
| ------------------- | ---------- | --------------------- |
| 2017-10-22 11:59:44 | 2017-10-22 | 2017-10-22 11:59:44.0 |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Verification of data types**

```
create table test2
select 
  from_unixtime(1508673584)                    as fut,
  cast(from_unixtime(1508673584) as date)      as futAsDate,
  cast(from_unixtime(1508673584) as timestamp) as futAsTimestamp;
```

And then

```
describe test2;
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------------
| col_name       | data_type | comment |
| -------------- | --------- | ------- |
| fut            | string    | <null>  |
| futAsDate      | date      | <null>  |
| futAsTimestamp | timestamp | <null>  |
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

create table test AS 
select cast(from_unixtime(1508673584) as timestamp) as fut;